# How to compare properties in OWL?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, reasoning

How would I represent the following reasoning in OWL/Protege?

> If molecules of type A have longer carbon chains then molecules of type B, then the boiling point of A is greater than that for B.

I unpack that statement as follows:

```
A_1 has property P_1 value V_11, property P_2 with value V_21
A_2 has property P_1 value V_12, property P_2 with value V_22

V_11 > V_12 therefore V_21 > V_22
```

I'm not sure how to represent the properties in OWL.

1. **Do I use a data property or object property restriction?** The expression "propane has a three-carbon chain" refers to all propane molecules, not just one individual propane molecule.
2. **How to represent comparison?** `V21 > V_22` is sufficient but not necessary for `V_11 > V12`.

Comment: You can't compare values in owl, most likely you should have a look at SWRL

Comment: You need to use rules for doing that. Hence SWRL is an option as @UninformedUser stated. You can also look at SHACL/SPIN/SHEX.

Answer (score 0):

you can include it in your data property in this case . Look into the Logical characteristics of properties section in the following link
[https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#:~:text=A%20property%20restriction%20is%20a,value%20constraints%20and%20cardinality%20constraints](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#:%7E:text=A%20property%20restriction%20is%20a,value%20constraints%20and%20cardinality%20constraints).